# AC to DC conversion without neutral

Tags: ac-dc, automation, esp32

I want to replace my wall switch with a smart switch which can be controlled by an ESP32. I need to use AC to DC conversion to get 3.3 V from 240 V, 50 Hz.

Some of the wall outlets have only phase and neutral, always directly connected to the appliance. In that case, I can't install an AC to DC converter for smart switch replacement.

I have seen in a product that I bought recently that it has only one phase for AC to DC conversion, and they were able to provide smart control also.

Is there any possible way to step down 240 V, 50 Hz to 3.3 VDC without using neutral? Would it be reliable if we do that?

Comment: See my answer to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/369773/73158 which explains some of the problems.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's impossible. You need a phase and a neutral for anything using electricity, including step-down converters.

What you can do, is to look for distribution boxes and find where the wires are going. Behind your old wall switches, there are at least two wires attached. If there are more than 2, then it's more complicated because you have to deal with go-and-return switches where two switches command the same appliance. So for the sake of simplicity, I will talk about the case when there is only one switch for one appliance and two wires on this switch.

If you can find and disconnect these two wires at the connection box and make 100% sure they are not connected to anything else, then you can reconnect them, one to neutral, the other to a phase.
Then, remains the question about the wires going from the smart switches to the appliance. If these wires don't exist, in any case you will have to add extra wires to complete the circuit. At this occasion, you can add proper wiring for the AC-DC supply + a Earth wire (yellow-green).

I advise you to do that with a friend or an acquaintance who knows a little bit about electrical installations and can help you on site. ;)

Comment: See my answer to electronics.stackexchange.com/a/369773/73158 which explains one circuit that works inline with the load and without a direct neutral connector.